# Mixed Reality Feature Tool.exe file not opening : For Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to set MRTK on my unity for Hololens2.

I downloaded MR feature tool from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=102778

I unziped this file, opened
[MixedRealityFeatureTool-1.0.2206.1-Preview],
and clicked exe file.
Nothing happenes when I click this. Nothing shows on task manager too.

I have already downloaded visual studio 2022 and .NET Runtime -5.0.0.

How can I fix this or make it work?

It works on my own notebook.. Maybe it's related to secure things on PC?

Comment: Do yo download the .NET runtime from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0 ? In addition, Is there any error message in the log file? please navigate to C:\Users\[xxxx]\AppData\Local\MixedRealityFeatureTool

Comment: @SethDU-MSFT I downloaded it from the link, dotnet-runtime-5.0.0-win-x64 was the file name. There was no MRFT file in that path..

Comment: Would you refer to learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to capture the process and you can filter the events by "PID name begins with mixedreality". Or simply use learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/… to open .exe and share the logs. Please remember to remove the personal information.

Comment: I solved this problem! It was blocked by company's security policy.